# Using UI, how to see if directory is a git submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am new to GIT... 
Using any UI, like Tortoise GIT or SourceTree, is there a way to quickly see if a directory is a GIT submodule or part of the local repo? 
I specifically do not want to use any command line commands to figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ah, just saw it:
for a submodule Tortoise will show menu "Git Commit Submodule". For a regular part of the tree it will just be "Git Commit".